# How to remove/ delete the space between bars and the panel in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

The following code produces the attached plot. How to get rid of/ remove the regions marked in **RED**?

```
    df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))
    ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

I modified the code as follows but no change.

```
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))
   
ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) +
   geom_col() + 
   theme(
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm")
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `expand` to 0 on both the axis :

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))

ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: i never know if its expand = c(0, 0) or expand = F. They both seem to work?

Comment: Yes, both of them seem to work the same way in this case.

Answer (score 1):

the margin option is for outside the plotting window. To change within the plotting window try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) +
  geom_col() + 
  coord_cartesian(expand = F)
```